# C# Form/Control Width Not Updating All the Time

Tags: c#, forms, label

I've made a small tool bar that sits in a transparent form, it loads a variable sized menu from a text file and can be changed on the fly. Each button is a type of Label, the bar is just a list of buttons and adds/removes them in the correct spots. Width of the form is only a little bigger than the menu bar so that sub menu isn't cut off

Everything is working sweet except, when I reload everything part of the toolbar is lost. I've attempted to change the width so many ways, I've cleared and removed the controls from the form, refreshing the form/menu, updating it etc however nothing seems to make it work as intended EXCEPT if I call the reload function twice in a row, it works. I can't see why calling it once doesn't work but calling it twice works.

I'm fine with calling reload twice in a row as it would only be called a couple times a week.

Question: what on earth is causing this?

[photo of issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpaFW.png) first photo shows what it should look like, second is after removing a menu button and reloading, third is after adding a button and reloading

```
//calling this.reload() doesn't work
//calling this.reload();this.reload() works
    void reload(Object o = null, EventArgs e = null)
    {
        this._menuBar.clear();
        this.loadFromFile();
    }
void loadFromFile(Object o = null, EventArgs e = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("kpi.txt"))
            {
                string cline = "", cmenu = "", lhs = "";
                menuList mb = null;

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("kpi.txt");
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    cline = sr.ReadLine();  //get current line
                    if (cline.Length > 0 && cline[0] != ';')
                    {
                        //check if main menu/command
                        if (cline[0] == '[')
                        {
                            cmenu = Regex.Match(cline, @"(?<=^\[)[a-zA-Z -\@_{-~\^\r\n]+(?=\])").Value;
                            if (cmenu != "")
                            {
                                mb = this._menuBar.addMenuButton(cmenu);
                                mb.data["options"] = Regex.Match(cline, @"\/\w+$").Value;
                                var match = Regex.Match(cline, @"(?<=<)([^>\[\]\r\n]+)(?=>)");
                                mb.data["count"] = (match.Success ? match.Value : "0");
                                mb.data["copy"] = "";
                                applyMenuOptions(mb, false);
                            }
                        }
                        //just a standard line
                        else
                        {
                            cline = cline.Trim();
                            lhs = Regex.Match(cline, @"^[^\;\<\[\]\r\n]+(?=$|\<|\;)").Value;
                            if (mb.getSubMenuItem(lhs) == null)
                            {
                                var newButton = mb.addSubMenu(lhs);
                                if (newButton != null)
                                {
                                    newButton.parent = mb;
                                    newButton.data["options"] = mb.data["options"];
                                    newButton.data["copy"] = Regex.Match(cline, @"((?<=\;)[^\[\]\<\r\n]+(?=<|$))").Value;
                                    var matches = Regex.Match(cline, @"(?<=<)([^>\[\]\r\n]+)(?=>)");
                                    int intout = 0;
                                    if (int.TryParse(matches.Value, out intout))
                                    {//no description
                                        newButton.data["description"] = "";
                                        newButton.data["count"] = intout.ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        newButton.data["description"] = matches.Value;
                                        newButton.data["count"] = (matches.NextMatch().Success ? matches.NextMatch().Value : "0");
                                    }
                                    applyMenuOptions(newButton);
                                    newButton.addMiddleClick(this.addcopy);
                                    if (newButton.data["options"].Contains("i"))
                                    {
                                        newButton.addRightClick(this.appendInfo);
                                        newButton.addRightClick(this.increment);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                this._menuBar.squish();
                this.Width = this._menuBar.Width+50;
            }
            else
            {
                menuList mb = this._menuBar.addMenuButton("menu");
                mb.data["options"] = "\\m";
                mb.data["count"] = "0";
                mb.data["copy"] = "";
                mb.data["description"] = "";
                applyMenuOptions(mb, false);
                saveDictonary();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to load data " + ex);
            //ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            //log.Info(ex);
        }
    }

    public menuList addMenuButton(string s, int w = 0, int h = 0, int x = -1, int y = -1)
    {
        menuList mb = new menuList(this._form, s);

        if (this.menuItems.Exists(z => z.Text == s)) return null;

        mb.Width = (w==0?settings.intOf("ButtonWidth"):w);
        mb.Height = (h==0?settings.IntOf("ButtonHeight"):h);
        if (x == -1 || y == -1)
            mb.Location = new Point(this.menuItems.Count > 0 ? this.menuItems.Last().Location.X + this.menuItems.Last().Width : padding);
        else mb.Location = new Point(x, y);

        mb.BringToFront();
        mb.Show();
        this.menuItems.Add(mb);
     //   this.Refresh();

        return mb;
    }

    internal void clear()
    {
        foreach(var i in this.menuItems)
        {
            this._form.Controls.Remove(i);
            i.clear();
           i.Dispose();
        }
        this.menuItems.Clear();
        this._form.Controls.Remove(this);


        this.menuItems = new List<menuList>();
        this._form.Controls.Add(this);
    }

    internal void squish()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Width = (this.menuItems.Count * this.menuItems.First().Width) + (2 * padding);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(""+ex); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit, bother the button class and the tool bar class were both adding themselves to the form control instead of button class adding to the tool bar (picture box) controls!

Removing transparency showed the buttons not moving when the tool bar was moved!